# Eye with Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, vertices, geometry-nodes

I am trying to create an eye according to the video tutorial ["[Blender 3.1] Eye Rig SLOW AND HARD tutorial (30 minutes)(geometry nodes)"](https://youtu.be/3TxZBbq8BMA). At the very beginning *(4:20)* I have difficulties.

a. I remove the vertex from the sphere.

b. I do *Extrude Edges* twice. The first time with a coefficient of 0.001 and the second time with zero.

c. I bring all 64 vertices to the 1*m* mark on the Y scale. *Absolut Grid Snaps* is on.

d. I arrange the geonodes as shown in the figure. I get a distorted sphere different from the sphere of the author.

[image]

The author's object has a different look than mine.

[image]

Is this possible due to individual coordinate system settings or other reasons? I have version 3.1 blender of standard configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His *Auto Merge Vertices* option is off (which merges points if they're very close to each other—like an automatic <kbd>M</kbd> *Merge—By Distance*). If yours is on, when you do the first extrude-then-scale operation, you'd get a single vertex for the iris instead of a very small circle. That could be the problem:

[image]

---

**Update after inspecting the file:** At the beginning of the tutorial, he rotates the sphere in *Edit Mode*. You must've rotated it in *Object mode*, which means its orientation was internally unchanged. Applying Rotation (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> *> Rotation*), or changing the *Cross Product* vector to the Z axis (`0, 0, 1`) fixes the problem:

[image]

Comment: I have AutoMerge turned off. I wouldn't have 64 vertices in this location. They would become one. I have Scene Statistics are enabled.

Comment: Can you share your file so we can take a look, then? You can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: OK. File is here. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sR5LwmJ6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sR5LwmJ6/)

Comment: @ГеннадийГорбач Updated the answer with the fix.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your help.